# Qbs, How to check byte order

Tags: qbs

How can byte order (big or little endianness) be checked from within Qbs? I do not know any other way to do it in Qbs or pure JavaScript. The idea is to avoid any other dependency from within Qbs, e.g. node.js' `os.endianness()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `cpp.endianness` property.

Comment: Can't seem to find it in the documentation though.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be missing. You might want to file a bug report at bugreports.qt.io.

Comment: Yes, this was added by 38bb125aae3ac592434446b8b02d14d4ef5618c0 which is present in v1.9.0. Looks like I forgot the doc entry. It will be present in the documentation once we release v1.9.1.

Comment: @ChristianKandeler, JakePetroules, any hint of the syntax/keyword involved? I can not figure out how.

Comment: Well, what do you want to do exactly and in which context? Rule? RHS of a property? ...?